# Dynamically Change JS Script src Attribute Based on php Select

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I have this php code which populates a `select` with a list of `.js` files from a directory.

```
<select id="s1" name="s1">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Employee</option>
    <?php
      foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/*.js') as $filename){
        $filename = basename($filename, ".js");
        echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
      }
      ?>
</select>
```

I have this `script` tag later on that loads a `.js` file:

```
<script src="data.js"></script>
```

How would I change the src attribute depending on the user selection of a file and refresh the page to demonstrate the contents with the new `.js` file?

Comment: It's not that simple. You actually will need to create a new `script` element with `document.createElement("script")` and then configure the `src` of that new element. You'd do this inside of a `change` event handler on the `select`.

Comment: hmm, makes conceptual sense - do you mind expanding upon that in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work by just altering the `src` attribute of an existing `script` because the browser will only parse that element one time. Changing the `src` after it's been parsed won't cause it to reload.

Instead, you need to create an entirely new `script` element, which you would then conditionally configure the `src` of and then append that into the document.

```js
// Get a reference to the select
var select = document.getElementById("s1");

// Set up a change event handler for it:
select.addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Create a new `<script>` element
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  
  // Conditionally set the src for the element
  switch(this.value){
    case "John" :
      script.src = "john.js";
      break;
    case "Mary" :
      script.src = "mary.js";
      break;
    case "Dave" :
      script.src = "dave.js";
      break;      
  }
  
  // Append the element to the document
  document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
  
  // Just for testing... scroll to the bottom to see the 
  // newly created element
  console.log(document.querySelector("head").innerHTML);

});
```

```html
<select id="s1" name="s1">
  <option value="" selected>Select Employee</option>
  <option>John</option>
  <option>Mary</option>
  <option>Dave</option>  
</select>
```

But, consider that if the user were to change the selected item from the dropdown, another new `script` element would be created and, in the end, you could wind up with a new `script` for each of the items. In which case, you may want to just consider statically linking to just one script file and having different functions within it and then just calling the right function based on the value of the dropdown list.